# My database won't accept strings with letters

Tags: string, mariadb

I'm using Mariadb and have the table setup with VARCHAR(30). When I insert a string containing numbers like "192" and then select it I'm able to print out 192. When I insert a string like "a48" it just seems to be ignored. I've tried inserting a complete letter string "a" and I still get nothing. In the Mariadb documentation for VARCHAR(M) I found this:

"If a unique index consists of a column where trailing pad characters are stripped or ignored, inserts into that column where values differ only by the number of trailing pad characters will result in a duplicate-key error"

I'm not sure if that could have anything to do with it? I am using letters just to make it easier to parse the data on my client side program. If I don't find a solution I will probably just pad it on the server after selecting.

Does anybody have any suggestions on what's going on here, or things I could try to find the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the actual insert statement?  Are you putting single quotes around the string, like 'a48'?

Comment: I'm taking data from php input and storing it in 2 variables. "REPLACE INTO state(id, melon, image) VALUES (1, $melon, $image)" I'm sending it to my php script with double quotes though.

Comment: so can you show the php code that is doing the insert, please?

Comment: `<?php $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);  if    ($data != null) {
$row_index = $data[row_index];
$melon = $data[button_a];
$image = $data[image_index];
}  
if ($row_index == 1) {

$connect->query("REPLACE INTO state (id, melon, image) VALUES (1, $melon, $image)");   

} ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that melon is the column to receive the string, then you should put single quotes around the $melon variable in the query, like this:

```
query("REPLACE INTO state (id, melon, image) VALUES (1, '$melon', $image)");
```

String values should be surrounded by single quotes; numeric values don't need to be.

Because the target column is a varchar(30) the value should always be surrounded by single quotes.  MariaDB works out what you mean when you supply a numeric value, but it doesn't understand an alphanumeric value without single quotes.  Both will work if you use single quotes, as shown.

To avoid SQL injection errors, it is better to use prepared statements, as described at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp.

Comment: That was the problem, I had originally set up the database with INT(30). Thanks!